# How to pass dummy gridview column in <ASP:HyperLinkField> URL as querystring

Tags: asp.net

I am facing problem in passing a dummy column's value in URL of `<asp:HyperLinkField>`.
My first column in gridview contains value from `<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1>` which gridview is populating however on click on my 2nd column which is a hyperlink field i want to pass value from 1st columns generated by `<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1>`.

So the problem here i am facing is how to pass a value as querystring which is not getting populated from database however is available as column in gridview.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the code so i can detect the problem and tell you what to do. Cos one thing you need to understand is the gridview tend itemize cell as zero index. So if your intention is to get say the ID of a table to a linkfieldbutton, i will advice you to use LinkButton.

Comment: this is something i usually do when i want to get value as querystring

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question:

Have you tried binding column 2 to the same field (`DataField`) column1 is so you can use the (same) data any way you want.

Alternatively, perhaps you can (already) use column1 for the same purpose (re: display and link)?

Hth....